# Understanding Closure concept in deep

Tags: javascript, closures

Hey check this code here,

```
function getspinner(){  
    var count = 0;  
    function increment(){  
        return ++count;  
    }  
    function decrement(){  
        return --count;  
    }
    return {  
        up:increment,  
        down:decrement  
    }  
}
```

If I call it like

```
var spinner = getspinner();  
spinner.up(); // value increments by 1 each time  
spinner.down(); // value decrements by 1 each time
```

But when I call it Like

```
getspinner().up(); // i'l get 1 each time  
getspinner().down(); // i'l get -1 each time
```

I would like to know the difference. why the lifetime of count is
not increased in case of getspinner().up() or getspinner().down();

Comment: Its because you are creating a new object of `getspinner` everytime you call by latter method whereas in first `var spinner = getspinner();`, you are creating an object of function & then using the same object everytime

Comment: Each call to `getspinner()` creates a new local variable `count` and new `increament` and `decreament` functions. How would they interact with each other? They can't. Here is a much simpler example of the effect you are seeing: `function foo() { return {bar: 42}; }; var a = foo(); var b = bar();` `a` and `b` are two different objects with no connection whatsoever. `a.bar++` would not change `b.bar`.

Comment: yes now I got the point, return value stored for each. I have done some experiments on console based on your answers... Thankyou guys